# Daily stock price changes and price returns per company

Tags: powerbi, dax, stockquotes

I have stock prices in a table:

| Date | Company | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-06 | AAPL | 142.92 |
| 2022-07-06 | AMZN | 114.33 |
| 2022-07-06 | MSFT | 266.21 |
| 2022-07-07 | AAPL | 146.35 |
| 2022-07-07 | AMZN | 116.33 |
| 2022-07-07 | MSFT | 268.4 |
| 2022-07-08 | AAPL | 147.04 |
| 2022-07-08 | AMZN | 115.54 |
| 2022-07-08 | MSFT | 267.66 |
| 2022-07-11 | AAPL | 144.87 |
| 2022-07-11 | AMZN | 111.75 |
| 2022-07-11 | MSFT | 264.51 |
| 2022-07-12 | AAPL | 145.86 |
| 2022-07-12 | AMZN | 109.22 |
| 2022-07-12 | MSFT | 253.67 |

I want to calculate day-to-day price changes and price returns by company. The result should look like this:

| Date | AAPL Price | AAPL Change | AAPL Return | AMZN Price | AMZN Change | AMZN Return | MSFT Price | MSFT Change | MSFT Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-06 | 142.92 |  |  | 114.33 |  |  | 266.21 |  |  |
| 2022-07-07 | 146.35 | 3.43 | 2.4% | 116.33 | 2.00 | 1.7% | 268.4 | 2.19 | 0.8% |
| 2022-07-08 | 147.04 | 0.69 | 0.5% | 115.54 | -0.79 | -0.7% | 267.66 | -0.74 | -0.3% |
| 2022-07-11 | 144.87 | -2.17 | -1.5% | 111.75 | -3.79 | -3.3% | 264.51 | -3.15 | -1.2% |
| 2022-07-12 | 145.86 | 0.99 | 0.7% | 109.22 | -2.53 | -2.3% | 253.67 | -10.84 | -4.1% |

Comment: Do you definitely want to do it in DAX? Presumably as a calculated table. Also, do you definitely want your table to be wide as opposed to narrow with a single column for company that you can then filter on?

Comment: I understand that "wide vs. long format" is just a matter of choosing the matrix visual over the table visual - as long as I have all the columns.

Comment: Do you need a table? If you are going to use a visual then it will be just 2 simple measures only.

Comment: Tell me more ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

Use a matrix and add these 3 measures.

```
Price Measure = MAX('Table'[Price]) 

Change = 
VAR cursor = MAX('Table'[Date])
VAR previousDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Date]), 'Table'[Date] < cursor)
VAR previousPrice = CALCULATE([Price Measure],'Table'[Date] = previousDate)

RETURN 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(previousPrice)),  [Price Measure] - previousPrice)

Return = [Change]/[Price Measure]
```

[image]

[S&P Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETOAoDuSRQm2xjmbXAAeSBDgA2cbfSSWGEBdqTaAZm0UoOABaWRpFOChMOFltByQATzYGS0w2bTJFZJxtOkQIXQSzN3IAhMppEAMaWXo0AEYAJgAGZpl4GjIsNAAWVpkcJFkw8TI0UCdfTDQBGWUu6dRZkDScBraQJjZsNgR1gF8ZJBS2CBoALzg0EEHZSqYkKABrTOTxO-QAYl8ANl8ADl8KBkZzI4iQDggaAA2qBwQgrugoNZKgwcLIStdqrUYNoCNpGiBDnC7IiQFAEqj0Zj0B0FniCUSpCSEddFAxJDJiBCGIigZC4DIJDDQHBSOJMFCkQ4aM8qRjotcAITsyT7AC6xJA8LJUDe0UUlW5Dl5DSFGlhIDFcAlUtAmASODJagRhpk9Cy2CcaEaAmahxAaIVZNVADJQ3qOQaADwAXl99QA-JGJXBFNoANTaeqoFMGpmi8WS8YrR1k2RMBxQGVygNBmkgZpEzXqmQKlCoS0664ASXeNm0mgcDlRihHtOweEIBFoEEw1DojCYHjTetTEsoeoQBAACgAhHvBAAiSGINQIAHYMX6BP8r0h6gIBEMAJwAZig-yGPV8+iY9TfGIeiYAhFCQAwCF8eogSgAQX2gpAmGaRpALfC83yg+pZGAi8eh6ep-jw-5ZCgeoejfZ8XwIPt5GsEQxDVZltVJXt+xRLkeQUEUQBomwzRAE9FXQFpGnqYJmgvcSL0qTRZGEbQAGEHFORFyNvSgAJkHdVxtRZ-VbFYwPECB-BMbiHSda5TIQBh4kqJApR4tjKhsHBDSRfU0wLUtLPQZS2CeNFKl8LI9nQXjrEHYdKieOBKXC5yZF8Gg4AcWQpWhJzaJAAzjV5DKQG0wJdMqQSrhkWT5KUlScqOAqiqCCVSsxCq5MU5TPFquQ4CBWy9I1LVu3QABlUMdyikcZAYMdriwXB8CIWd51oehmBXQIJGiDct13A9j1Pc97xvO8MUfZ9ZHfT9v1-OB-0A7CQLAiD-jfJgoBfHokDgJABDgJ8ejvJBkMaPpfx+oEL0Il8fkQpBfAvKCCFGncAFJfRaQSkDRgQWiHBx6OFQaWJGsbR3HDBJwWmcaDnBdVuXTwNvXecdv3Q8TzPWRL2vZpb3vM7Xw-L9sJuu6gMe8CCBfXwmCBJp-hfbD6n0WRGiQRpfHfCsyIVn5migKDZCvF8oHegQkbG7GMbcYFDKQYzrPMssrICGy7Lq64ADk4AMbQAGk4pc6w3OuBUGAQSgFN2QZxASDM8y8rULLJfzArWJLQuuZGJpiwP0ADykkpStKCu932C66vKuM7QqdKamQysqYaYGMZwd2UIIuocmFa+K+uBJakBm9b7R29lK4DPkXqHH6lsQSgCFq67YmQASaBF8qZPrhlcRvrdORdiQGgLWCepKEaKQz8aAyjLIMk6W6InWXQax1+9d1nfQB53kqWRD+PnuUcEA2XELKNw6htDDTTGeIIUIZB7gcrKbQABZEoygIRwJAFHYy4c0yKQSNWMBk0sESAgLg9MR4eo2jOKQSoABRXeigyCFxAAAFUiDAcQbBlLMMqAAJW+g4bQdC5yDwAGLH3tlAGgEJIHQPHpggAqmoGUaguIyAABKCPoAvCIlQaIeEwOgyEXVb5kmxHUJ+upuEBE3p-EAAQRgQl-v-DQoB2xZ1JkXVKHwh6RDSIaAMZiSxcEQLqEoZAygtCJFY64ZxLguOQAA1A7ibaeJ3MFYuvjUGKFipYBSSA1hBPtnfGEbQ-StDniAJwd93gZVAPEskjTN50G9OgHJeTFKFMqAEFKTV0BcN3pUGpNpZAAA1ej9GqeQUZABNNAp83wbD1CaBA4gdxDBGGMVALQ5hsAMBs4Yx9tn1A2GwXwvhPCLCWe6VpcBNDiFgLY9AojFDTFuZgJwhytk+g2GoT5cAADyygSroFWC0gFUdlLuRAJ8OC8KXy-3CP49Qs1ennE2s4kECQEBbAcBI4cULnmwrgC+UlpLKgQBxXi4aRiApwAAOo1DqKgZolBlhUtxdw1h9jpGBHflaR5bB5AlniHoExKTAzUiEvaGwiwGmdHBOTMOEcxWpUzAAcj3BqmJ+w9UGSQNYJeoBemgs2NsNIex54bxfm-cqIBMg1DQEY3kbZXFoH5J4W5zwpSesFNUxCqUxGbWGhcRE9R6gyDVfizaDK4CdG6OgCplRHWyCZTiNAbLlipsBYMaRDpM2UH+FGwNDgiUwrhS+BFLkhUisldGu0UrgwllkPFS00Q5yhzcOHSg0btCxljFqxBUAUFoJkZCDVAAfSdKre2lv7YO7BZDXTaEob+YyNBSBTpnd21V86B0aokeCR5465GKBgQobds6+0Hq0RCHRrcr27rneKhdGr2GwC4TwhIOqOImkRL6LUVcZgDT1VqU1-TplTEpQvNpq87XBVdm4a4KMU3KA+C6-1ahnhRyjGgYtKxZRPF9Rg-10bg0SlDQk1AEa3VJI0H6mQqb00sqzUx9DubHh0Himygj0by3XErdWmQNo9R1tAKmks9YZUgDnFkWK5kFCLDkM+m9g7mgo1-SAYDX94i1iYjp2TNAHCkECZqMDBlkC5PqT5EMtl7UhV2C2tJCVsoBlE8KxEoBpNedk3ShTkrDOVkeE8Jkfn5OMuZTAEsOms0Bjk-Sk8EBouBc4jCSN9RNQyBRJK0ESqsRRbC9YQkqX-2ZoDPFBpsGyRr2q5knx1wGolTA0nex0RrDvJAI5sKqTMAdiynxdztbfM+ZLBCRVMW0t+R6tMAMDxPA7184ZhANRZDegDO1+VRmwTOPQBq7O2gNWZj8EhzAAAKWdTWJRSEO2y+ommACUYXZA5dADpxoAZkrRVK6aL4CK4JFZLMlBrkrXhBXQBY6LeqZCVdk3V9AtWN7eLSo1uus2ZDnGPtlH7AGWtMSGtqTzmCt4vOpdw4KmdJUeJJhkobYnfO6S8rlsNQOsnXA6XAfJ3TrVweaZ94z44qs2vJDY-ewOUcjX8bY6HTaaSgGsP4KAHgQnw5AK-OryPfFQKiLYmQ38PhxZh4r5XuXVeI4FeL3xV30fhfpZNsrumQthYS7FFjKW3tTcNyATHzkccNA22wbhag1jM52+TYAGqgExx-agWdUf7ZFBu-tqXigNWx+fdrgJ2gpAao51znAaeVXQlz8YTpBSC-qgzFqo7Ofrdp5OyYNwF3n3W6T3dx7Ofh4RFHh3OA9ei-7Zbt3seQQNWtg1WVfvu7i+T81Lq90RkTKuydr5LrARO5zCUxYZ17J-UQhwC3QtF81-FRs6ZTuHlhw1HtXkMCahSG9BBEYm0ZBWPsrmEMGgJvRTBxhRAAAjm8s3pgD2o0g9gyISNDqAOfmSOxGrtcArmwErpgnJi-iyvUFqDAdcCwvFKvMbigc-qMOgQNFlvaG1nKhTk5lTi5oTvIFCHTp5iWIzu5KAONmCPbr9uSMwWFvNqlMfEtlNiACtsMOtklCGizn7jRv6GIRKHGgmltkFtwncPzt9h7g7lUDAHkDElNNKr5q9l1mzi-GFrDpbtgWFmkEHioCEoqrtiABHvHrHIXs+nHtHAntnodpngEE4SARHLOp4emEnnnl0gXunj4ZQAPkEeXmPlXtqtnhqnXqgA3sgOdrOpdmjm3hpB3oPiPCPn3okakdPtkcPr3mPjnpPvkc4YUbPvsOYRQZ2LKp2ugAUT4cXpEYUmPtoNGNoEsk2H+pwd5KYU0c+g4ZSKBq1qvptr-C5rCBqCJsNlJroSWJMZIZlMNMkMVIkbMkgDAIHkqNoEelIvapjGeOcIkRzDUNoAgqbDQDlAGGwW4tpoIZMDbotlovIRweGj8CoYLo8eoUJlWoigGPoXlrYZDtoMENmK0MYdYWHrNPGvSFmKck2J9uIdRmob9qcnjmQRMRQRnFQb1v1hFGFh5uJrLjJssQqrCUMWEWVMdkdsNDuLModsdtZE3mkX3JgBkfdhqk9ncTKOwZIVBjbl9j8YZp8EELIM0KrIDqHvlugMEEstCbKbYeCX6GFv4JRhIeiYiBRC1pqEAA) referred to in the comment

Comment: Amazingly clean  solution - thanks!

Comment: Peter - if you're comfortable with Deneb (custom visual in PowerBI), then I recently created the following which is S&P performance over the last year. You can easily have this in PowerBI. I have to add the link to the answer at the end as the url is too long for a comment. Click to animate the visual to see it cycle through each day.